# Const references in std::vector elements

Tags: c++, stl, reference, vector, constants

Is it only my compiler or is it forbidden to use cons references in std::vector elements. Consider following structure:

```
struct Y
{
  const int & x;

  Y(const int & p_x):
        x(p_x)
  {
  }
};
```

Now, when I try to push such object onto vector:

```
std::vector<Y> yv;
int x = 5;
Y y(x);
yv.push_back(y);
```

I get compiler error: "error: non-static reference member `const int&Y::x', can't use default assignment operator". Shouldn't copy ctor be enough?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `vector` elements must be assignable. From section *23.2.4 Class template vector* of the C++ standard:

> ...the stored object shall meet the requirements of Assignable.

Answer (score 15):

You may want to check

```
std::reference_wrapper
```

available with C++11

Comment: Or I believe `boost::reference_wrapper` for pre C++11

Comment: This is a useful answer but it would highly benefit from some explanation/example on what `std::reference_wrapper` does and how it is used.

Answer (score 5):

No, because you can't assign to a const reference and the STL containers make use of assignment for moving items around.

You're better using a `shared_ptr` (`boost::` or `std::` depending on your environment) or a raw pointer.

Answer (score 1):

An assignment operator is necessary because `vector` default constructs elements in extra slots ahead of time.

Later, instead of reallocating, it uses the assignment operator to assign those default instances to whatever you push into the vector.

Answer (score 0):

It is generally forbidden to use references in any container. You can justify this by the fact, that a vector for example allocates the data in forehand and references can just be assigned once (during initialization).

Answer (score 0):

I finally used

```
 std::vector< const Type* >
```

Not the best looking, but it does the same job.